# Expected property type size

Tags: qt, qml

I'm starting to learn QML.

I found [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qml-size.html) that there is the 'size' type in QML. But when I'm trying to use it:

```
property size buttonSize: "75x30"
```

I get the error:

```
Button.qml:13:14: Expected property type 
         property size buttonSize: "75x30" 
                  ^
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`size` is not directly supported as a property type.

The supported types are listed [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qml-extending-types.html#supported-property-types).

You can also use a `variant` to store the size:

```
property variant buttonSize: Qt.size(75,30)
```